# How to 'clear' main page on Twitter and move people I follow into a list

Tags: twitter

I have recently started using Twitter. I am following a number of people - but some of them are tweeting every 5 seconds, so my main page is cluttered with their tweets. I want to create a list (I think that is what its called), and move the people that I follow into a list instead. The whole idea is so that my tweets (about once every few days) will still appear on my "home page", and that the "noisy" people I follow will not drown everyone else out.

What I want to do is to have a less busy "homepage", so that my infrequent tweets do not get drowned by people I follow.

Can someone explain the steps involved in:

1. creating a list (if that is what I need to do)
2. "Clearing out" my "homepage" on twitter, so that only my tweets appear there

Also:

Is there anyway of following someone without having their incessant tweeting drowning out your tweets?

Answer (score 3):

Please consult http://support.twitter.com/

Specifically [How to Use Twitter Lists](http://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists)

> There are a few ways to create a new
>   list, the easiest way is by clicking
>   “New list” on the twitter sidebar.
>   Clicking on this link will pop up a
>   box, as shown above. Here you can name
>   your list. You can also make the list
>   public (everyone can see it) or
>   private (only you can see it).

The homepage will always have the timeline of everyone you follow.
The profile page (twitter.com/username) will always have your tweets

The noisy users can be handled by this question

[How can I throttle an over talkative person I'm following on Twitter without unfollowing?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/983/how-can-i-throttle-an-over-talkative-person-im-following-on-twitter-without-unfo)